Twitch API send message not working using websockets
so I am creating a EventSub via websockets once the websocket is open then it waits for a notification ("message") and it will send a message to the chat of the broadcaster that works well but then if you try to do that a second time it doesnt do it. it console logs it but it doesnt appear on the chat on twitch. when i console log the data of the sent message the message id is the exact same one for all the messages
    let websocketSessionID;
    
    // Function to start the WebSocket client
    function startWebSocketClient() {
      const websocketClient = new WebSocket(EVENTSUB_WEBSOCKET_URL);
    
      websocketClient.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket connection opened to ' + EVENTSUB_WEBSOCKET_URL);
      };
    
      websocketClient.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
      };
    
      websocketClient.onmessage = (event) => {
        try {
          const dataInfo = JSON.parse(event.data);
          console.log('Received WebSocket message:', dataInfo);
    
          if (dataInfo.metadata.message_type === 'session_welcome') {
            websocketSessionID = dataInfo.payload.session.id;
            console.log('WebSocket Session ID:', websocketSessionID);

        // Call the function to subscribe to the event once the session ID is received
        subscribeToChatMessage();
      }

      if (dataInfo.metadata.message_type === 'notification') {
        console.log('Notification received:', dataInfo.payload.event);
        console.log('Message Text:', dataInfo.payload.event.message.text);

        // Call the function to send a chat message
        sendChatMessage('Hello, world! I am testing this thing out');
      } } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing WebSocket message:', error);
    }
  };
}

// Function to subscribe to the channel.chat.message event
function subscribeToChatMessage() {
  const url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/eventsub/subscriptions';
  const accessToken = OAUTH_TOKEN;
  const clientId = CLIENT_ID;

  const requestBody = {
    type: 'channel.chat.message',
    version: '1',
    condition: {
      user_id: BOT_USER_ID,
      broadcaster_user_id: CHAT_CHANNEL_USER_ID
    },
    transport: {
      method: 'websocket',
      session_id: websocketSessionID,
    },
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Client-Id': clientId,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((errorData) => {
          throw new Error(`Request failed: ${errorData.message}`);
        });
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Subscription created successfully:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

function sendChatMessage(message) {
  const url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/chat/messages';
  const accessToken = OAUTH_TOKEN;
  const clientId = CLIENT_ID;

  const requestBody = {
    broadcaster_id: CHAT_CHANNEL_USER_ID,
    sender_id: BOT_USER_ID,
    message: message
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'Client-Id': clientId,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((errorData) => {
          throw new Error(`Request failed: ${errorData.message}`);
        });
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Chat message sent successfully:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

// Start the WebSocket client
startWebSocketClient();

